# Force permissions/ownership on a directory and everything in it

Tags: linux, permissions

I have a directory and I'd like all the files in it to be always permissioned and owned in a certain way, regardless which user edits them.

This gets close:

```
# users: wilma, betty
# group: devs contains wilma and betty.
# directory: 'dir'

chgrp -R devs dir
find dir -type d -exec chmod 2770 \{\} \+
find dir -type f -exec chmod 660 \{\} \+
setfacl -d -R -m group:devs:rwx dir
setfacl    -R -m group:devs:rwx dir
```

But it still gets messed up if one of the users uses chmod (resets acl masks) and a couple of other situations that I've seen in real life but not nailed down how it happened yet!

I basically don't want those users to be able to change the permissions.

The only way I can think to do this is resorting to making a vfat fs and mounting that over the dir!

Comment: default  `facl`s work, except for the case of users intentionally changing them. I think there maybe something you can do with mount options, of fuse file-systems. Have you also tried asking your users why they are doing it?

Comment: I can train users to some extent, however they use tools and processes which have chmod embedded in them - annoyingly - which are hard to patch.

Comment: @artfulrobot Did you try the Linux Security Modules way ? configuring AppArmor or SELinux or equivalent to restrict access to `chmod(2)` granularly would do that, though not in an easy and straightforward way as doing with regular permission bits

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the fuse file system [bindfs](https://bindfs.org/) to accomplish this.

e.g. if you have a directory of files that you want users wilma and betty to be able to share, both with write accesss, and both unable to restrict the access of the other.

Say Wilma is the main user (you could pick a third user for this purpose) and they're both in the 'devs' group.

```bsh
wilma% mkdir src -m760
wilma% echo some content >src/file-created-by-wilma
wilma% mkdir shared
wilma% bindfs src shared -g devs -u wilma -p770 -m wilma:betty --create-with-perms=660
```

Now that's set up create some files inside this shared mount by the two users ...

```
wilma% cd shared
wilma% echo hi>file-created-by-wilma-inside-bindfs

betty% cd /path/to/shared
betty% echo hi>file-created-by-betty-inside-bindfs
```

View the files inside the mounts. Note that each user sees themself as the owner!

```
wilma% ls -l
-rwxrwx--- 1 wilma devs file-created-by-willma
-rwxrwx--- 1 wilma devs file-created-by-willma-inside-bindfs
-rwxrwx--- 1 wilma devs file-created-by-betty-inside-bindfs


betty% ls -l
-rwxrwx--- 1 betty devs file-created-by-willma
-rwxrwx--- 1 betty devs file-created-by-willma-inside-bindfs
-rwxrwx--- 1 betty devs file-created-by-betty-inside-bindfs
```

View the 'actual' files...

```
wilma% ls -l src/
-rw-rw--- 1 wilma wilma file-created-by-willma
-rw-rw--- 1 wilma wilma file-created-by-willma-inside-bindfs
-rw-rw--- 1 wilma wilma file-created-by-betty-inside-bindfs
```